# Permission denied when accessing local PHP web service from Android app project

Tags: php, android, eclipse, stack-trace

I am working on an Android app that calls web services written in PHP. Currently the web services are hosted on my local machine using MAMP (Mac OS Mt. Lion). I am accessing them through a URL specified with an internal IP address, since a virtual machine cannot access localhost. The URL appears as follows:

```
http://10.0.1.12:8888/platform/services/_login.php?un=joe&pw=pword&ref=cons
```

Here is the code calling the web service (passed in as 'serviceEndpoint'):

```
public String readJSONFeed(String serviceEndpoint){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serviceEndpoint);

    try{
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode == 200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } else {
            Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("readJSONFeed ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        StackTraceElement[] errors = ex.getStackTrace();
        for(StackTraceElement error : errors){
            Log.d("TRACE", error.toString());
        }
    }       
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The exception is being caught in the handler and the only info I can extract is 'Permission Denied'. The web service is fully accessible through a browser. I am attempting to run this on a physical Android device. Any ideas as to how to solve this issue? Thanks, Viv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this in you manifest file? If not, try adding it

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```